# Type Mismatch: cannot convert from PolarAngleComparator to Comparator<Point>

Tags: java, comparator

```
public abstract class Sorter
{
     protected Comparator<Point> pointComparator;
     private Point lowestPoint;
     ...
     protected void setComparator()
     {
          if (condtion)
               pointComparator = new PolarAngleComparator(lowestPoint);
     }
 }
 public class PolarAngleComparator implements Comparator<Point>
 {
      private Point referencePoint;
      public PolarAngleComparator(Point p)
      {
           referencePoint = p;
      }        
      public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
      {
         if(p1.equals(p2))
         {
             return 0;
         }
         else if (p1.equals(referencePoint) || !p1.equals(referencePoint) && 
         !p2.equals(referencePoint) && comparePolarAngle(p1, p2) == -1 ||
         !p1.equals(referencePoint) && !p2.equals(referencePoint) && 
         comparePolarAngle(p1, p2) == 0 && compareDistance(p2, p2) == -1)
         {
            return -1;
         }
         else
         {
            return 1;
         }
     }
  }
```

The following is my code I'm working on for an assingment. The issue I'm having is occuring in my abstract class when I attempt to assign `new PolarAngleComparator(lowestPoint)` to `pointComparator`. The error thrown is Type mismatch: cannot convert from PolarAngleComparator to Comparator. I implemeted Comparator, but I'm still confused as to why this assignment is throwing an error. Any advice or knowledge on this situation/comparators in general would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public int comparePolarAngle(Point p1, Point p2) 
{
    if(crossProduct(p1, p2) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(p1.equals(referencePoint) || crossProduct(p1, p1) > 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

    private int crossProduct(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int p1x = (int) (p1.getX() - referencePoint.getX());
    int p1y = (int) (p1.getY() - referencePoint.getY());
    int p2x = (int) (p2.getX() - referencePoint.getX());
    int p2y = (int) (p2.getY() - referencePoint.getY());
    return ((p1x*p2y)-(p1y*p2x)); 
}
```

Comment: You should name your post title properly.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Also, you need to post the error, you didn't posted complete code. So, how would we know what else you have done correctly ?

Comment: Apologies, the error is as follows: Type mismatch: cannot convert from PolarAngleComparator to Comparator<Point>

Comment: I just compiled your code. I didn't get any error.

Comment: OP has totally misleading post. `comparePolarAngle` is not shown anywhere in the code. The existing code has only issue with `comparePolarAngle ` method otherwise it compiles without any issue.

Comment: @Ravi Would it be helpful if I provided more code?

Comment: you should atleast provide code for `comparePolarAngle`

Comment: @Ravi Please see my latest edit for comparePolarAngle method

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: @NabinBhandari Still the same problem, just trying to provide more context

Answer (score 0):

Define your class as

```
public class PolarAngleComparator <Point> implements Comparator <Point>{
}
```

Or replace `protected Comparator <Point> pointComparator;` with `protected Comparator pointComparator;` if you don't want to use generics in your class.

Make sure you go through the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: if he wouldn't have implemented `compare` method. Then, he would have got error before only. Not during initializing

Comment: And, you never know, he might have implemented `compare` method, as he hasn't share complete code

Comment: Did you even tried compiling his code ? I didn't get any error while compilation. It's not reproducible

Comment: @Ravi I am from phone. How can an object of class without generic type be assigned to the object with generic type?

Comment: It can. It will become raw type. You can try yourself. It is not good to answer as per assumption. Even, I thought first, but get it confirm from compiler.

Comment: You could open ideone.com from your phone and try executing 
`List<String> lst = new ArrayList();` You won't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your "three dots" below the PolarAngleComparator's constructor represents the implementation of the `compare()` method (stated from the interface).

```
public abstract class Sorter {
    protected Comparator<Point> pointComparator;
    private Point lowestPoint;

    protected void setComparator() {
        pointComparator = new PolarAngleComparator(lowestPoint);
    }
}

public class PolarAngleComparator implements Comparator<Point> {
    private Point referencePoint;

    public PolarAngleComparator(Point p) {
        referencePoint = p;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return 0; //TODO: Implement comparator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine. You must have messed up the import statements. Make sure you have imported the same class in both places.